# Fluent Bit Event Format Issue

Tags: logging, fluent, fluent-bit

**Question:**
I’m working with Grafana Loki and Fluentd on an EKS cluster. On my IoT device, I have Fluent Bit installed to forward logs to Fluentd. By default, Fluent Bit sends logs in the format `[[TIMESTAMP, METADATA], MESSAGE]`. However, I’m trying to forward only the `MESSAGE` part to Fluentd since Grafana Loki is already capturing its own timestamp.

Currently, the output from Fluent Bit looks like:

```
[0] sensor: [[1692719658.517654104, {}], {“log”=>“hello”}]
```

When Grafana Loki receives this, it appears as:

```
2023-08-22 17:54:18.935 log=hello
2023-08-22 17:54:18.935 [2023-08-22 14:54:18.090994403 +0000, {}]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb9dh.png)

**What I want to achieve:**

1. Forward only the `MESSAGE` part from Fluent Bit, excluding the timestamp.
2. If the timestamp cannot be excluded, ensure the message is forwarded in a single line instead of two.

Here’s my Fluent Bit configuration:

```ini
[SERVICE]
    Flush        1
    Daemon       Off
    Log_Level    debug

[INPUT]
    Name         tail
    Path         /path/to/file/text.txt
    Tag          sensor

[OUTPUT]
    Name         http
    Match        *
    Host         my-host
    Port         80

[OUTPUT]
    Name          stdout
    Match         *
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before in a similar setup? Is there a workaround or a recommended approach to achieve this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!